# How to keep uploaded documents from master branch after checkout to a tag?

Tags: git, version-control, server

I followed the next steps to update a production server:

From my local master branch.

1. `git tag name_of_my_tag`
2. `git push origin name_of_my_tag`
3. `git fetch --tags origin name_of_my_tag`

From remote server.

1. `git fetch --tags origin`
2. `git checkout name_of_my_tag`

But when I searched my uploaded documents files from current tag, they are no longer exist and the dir which contains them it's empty, but in my master branch they exists. Does this mean that a `git checkout name_of_my_tag` does not keeps uploaded files from master branch?

How can I make that the uploaded files from my master branch are present in name_of_my_tag too?

If I do a git merge origin/master, this throws a LOT of merge conflicts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had no other options than to deal with those many conflicts (couldn't wait longer for an answer here). This is what I did to solve this problem:

1. `git checkout name_of_my_tag`
2. `git rebase master`
3. End

Weird thing was that from my local this happened:

1. `git checkout name_of_my_tag`
2. `git rebase master`
3. `ag -i "<<< HEAD"` (no file contained the string, so I supposed there weren't errors, maybe?...)
4. `git add .`
5. `git rebase --continue`
6. At this point git complained about no files to be added... don't know why.
7. `git rebase --skip`
8. End

If you have a better way to solve this, that would be great. But for now, I hope this could be of any help for anyone with the same or similar problem.